# This Function Using .Find Can't Completely Finish

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a list of objects I need to compare to another list; more specifically I need to take each individual item of this list:

```
GAC-CR-02918
GVII-GER-2166
GVII-G600-GSN-552001
739124.003
GVII-G600-GSN-551002
GVII-G600-GSN-533001
735330.001
735750.001
GVII-GER-2309
730000.001
GVII-GER-0775
```

and I need to .Find them on a much larger list of items.  I know that these are all in the larger list because I already went through and found them manually using the Search And Replace tool.

Here is my code:

```
Function g600BurndownUser()
  With Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:T2500")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter 20, "y"
    .AutoFilter 13, ""
    .Rows.Sort Key1:=Columns("A"), Order1:=xlAscending
    .Rows.Sort Key1:=Columns("E"), Order1:=xlAscending
    .Copy
  End With
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1:N2500").NumberFormat = "@"
  Range("A1:A2500").PasteSpecial
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
  Dim counter As Integer, countyBoi(1 To 100), textValue As String, offsetValue As Integer, startingPoint As Range
  Set startingPoint = Range("A1:N2500").Find("Report Number"): offsetValue = 1
  For counter = LBound(countyBoi) To UBound(countyBoi)
    If startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value = "*note: only over-due G600 Cert Reports are included on this list" Then
      Exit For
    End If
    If startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value <> "*note: only over-due G600 Cert Reports are included on this list" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
      Range("A1:A2500").Select
      Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
      startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
      textValue = startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A2500").Find(textValue, LookIn:=xlValues).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
      offsetValue = offsetValue + 1
    End If
  Next counter
End Function
```

I already know that the code works because it highlights every item that it goes over on the smaller list in magenta, and the duplicate of the item that it finds on the larger list in cyan.  However, my problem lies with every item in the smaller list that starts with a seven (i.e. 739124.003).  It will highlight the item magenta to show that it is using that value to .Find it, but the function will end there, and not find that value.

Is there anything I can do here?  Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Can you try amending your `.Find(textvalue, LookIn:=xlValues)` to `.Find(textvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)` and see if your results are more like what you expected?

Comment: I'll try that out and let you know what happens.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, I believe the line where you increment your offsetvalue should probably be discarded as you keep offsetting by a higher value as your loop progresses, remove the line `offsetValue = offsetValue + 1` and I'm not sure where you assign the values to `countyBoi`, but I guess that's not an issue if your code does actually reach the For Loop.

Comment: Hey, you're suggestions worked flawlessly, thanks so much for the advice.

Comment: no worries, glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd add my version of the potential solution below, literally just cleaned up the code a little, removed any .Activate / .Select and changed the If statement with an ElseIF, please have a look as it may come in handy:

```
Function g600BurndownUser()
Dim counter As Integer, countyBoi(1 To 100), textValue As String, offsetValue As Integer, startingPoint As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:T2500")
      .AutoFilter
      .AutoFilter 20, "y"
      .AutoFilter 13, ""
      .Rows.Sort Key1:=Columns("A"), Order1:=xlAscending
      .Rows.Sort Key1:=Columns("E"), Order1:=xlAscending
      .Copy
    End With

    ws2.Range("A1:N2500").NumberFormat = "@"
    ws2.Range("A1:A2500").PasteSpecial

    Set startingPoint = ws.Range("A1:N2500").Find("Report Number")
    offsetValue = 1

    For counter = LBound(countyBoi) To UBound(countyBoi)
          If startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value = "*note: only over-due G600 Cert Reports are included on this list" Then
              Exit For
          ElseIf startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value <> "*note: only over-due G600 Cert Reports are included on this list" Then
              ws.Range("A1:A2500").NumberFormat = "@"
              startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
              textValue = startingPoint.Offset(offsetValue, 0).Value
              ws2.Range("A1:A2500").Find(textValue, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
          End If
    Next counter
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; along with the comments from Xabier, I also found that for some strange reason if the column is too short and it cuts out the number, it only searches for what's visible, so that was part of my problem.  Thanks for the cleaned up code, as well!